# Call from c code a kernel variable in freebsd

Tags: c, global-variables, variable-assignment, freebsd

I found some online resources about this topic but still can not understand how it works.

Lets assume that I have a global variable with following specification
in file: /sys/sys/sysctl.h

```
#define USER_TZNAME_MAX     20   /*test var*/
```

and in file /usr/src/sys/kern/kern_mib.c a

```
SYSCTL_INT(_user, USER_TZNAME_MAX, tzname_max, CTLFLAG_RW, 0, 0, "something");
```

can anyone show practically how to change the variable value and set another value in a c source file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`#define USER_TZNAME_MAX` is **not** defining a global variable, it is a preprocessor macro.

Before the compiler compiles the code the preprocessor is run to expand macros and include/exclude code as defined by definitions.

In an example such as this, the preprocessor will replace all instances of the string "USER_TZNAME_MAX" in the source with the string "20":

```
// this
int i = USER_TZNAME_MAX;

// will be expanded to this:
int i = 20;
```

Therefore you **can't** change this variable at run time because a) it isn't a variable, and b) it's a constant.

If you're talking about changing the value used in your own code you can do this:

```
#ifdef USER_TZNAME_MAX
#undef USER_TZNAME_MAX
#endif

#define USER_TZNAME_MAX (32)
```

Comment: I picked this variable just as an example. What about the command: sysctl -w variablenewvalue. This is what I am trying to do from my code. I want to chande and acces in code the actual value of user.tzname_max, the result which is print after running from command line sysctl user.tzname_max

Answer (score 0):

In programs, you should  use [sysctl(3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&sektion=3) to get or set system information.